# aSimpleTour.js (jQuery Plugin) - How do I properly initialize and use this plugin across multiple independent pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a very initial, not complete and preliminary mod of aSimpleTour for generating an onboarding feature for a 2 to 3 page tour of a website.

**Plugin Link is** 
http://alvaroveliz.github.io/aSimpleTour/

Due in part to my entry level knowledge of this plugin I have been struggling to get a working prototype of this plugin with an existing application.

My goal is to initialize the tour to jump across multiple pages with different content.

**Question**

How do I properly use this plugin to jump to multiple pages using my own container for each page?

**My initialization code is as follows.**

```
<script>
var tour = {
                autoStart: true,
                useOverlay: false,
                data : [
                    {  tooltip:'', stepText: '2 of 3', message: 'page 2 content', position: 'TL', location: '/#/app/page2#tour=2'},
                    {  tooltip:'', stepText: '3 of 3', message: 'page 3 content', position: 'TL', location: '/#/app/page3#tour=3'}
                ],
                stepText: '1 of 3',
                message: 'page 1 content',
                location: '/#/app/page1#tour=1',
                controlsPosition : 'TL',
                buttons: {
                    next  : { text : 'Let\'s Do It', class : 'btn-green'},
                    //prev  : { text : '&larr; Previous', class: 'btn btn-default' },
                    //start : { text : 'Start', class: 'btn btn-primary' },
                    end   : { text : 'Skip', class: 'btn-gray' }
                },
                controlsCss: {
                  //  background: 'rgba(124, 124, 124, 0.9)',
                  //  color: '#fff',
                    width: '250px',
                    'border-radius': '0px'
                }
            };

            $(document).ready(function(){
                    $.aSimpleTour(tour);
            });
</script>
```

**Library's Modified Controls Declaration**

```
controls = '<div id="tourControls" class="account-settings-confirm-container-overlay filter-drop-shadow">\
  <div id="tourText" class="overlay-text">\
      <div id="confirm-step">'+
        + options.stepText +
      '</div><div id="message">'+
      options.message+
    '</div></div>\
    <div id="tourButtons" class="action-buttons">\
        <button id="tourEnd" class="btn-gray">SKIP</button>\
        <button id="tourNext" class="btn-green">LET\'S DO IT</button>\
    </div>\
  </div>';
```